# stay online on whatsapp web and offline in mobile

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I want to stay online on whatsapp web whenever i want after scanning the qr code but with mobile data being off on mobile. so is it possible? I have search a lot but didn't get a possible solution!! please help if there is!!

Comment: Not possible with WhatsApp. Maybe some hacked WhatsApp can do that and you can experiment at your own risk

Answer (score 1):

Simply it is not possible.

*WhatsApp Web is a computer based extension of the WhatsApp account on your phone*.

*The messages you send and receive are fully synced between your phone and your computer.*

The first requirement to being able to use WhatsApp Web is an ***active*** WhatsApp account on your ***smartphone***.

*If you cannot connect to WhatsApp on your phone to send and receive messages, then you will not be able to use WhatsApp Web.*
- According to the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/web/28080002)

So basically, it just access your phone to sync data.

And this [on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-WhatsApp-web-work-only-when-the-phone-is-connected-to-the-internet) discuss the details.